# can we please add a way to view modifier keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, cache, alembic

I mess with a lot of alembic files and I animate the alembic cache sometimes. The problem is I can't see the keyframes. They don't show up in the graph editor, they don't show up in the dope sheet, they don't show up in the timeline. I want to actually view my keyframes. I think it's silly for an animation software to give you the ability to key every numerical value then just say screw it to displaying it in the timeline... [image]

Comment: You're asking in the wrong place! There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here have any association with the Blender Foundation. Suggest you add a suggestion on the [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot) site.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For suggestions and feature requests use https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect or https://blenderartists.org. Before doing so consider that ideas are a dime-a-dozen, what we lack is manpower. Every single one of the millions of users have their own long list of personal wishes and desires, while comparatively very few people have the knowledge and inclination to actually implement them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While usually the keyframes show up in *Timeline*, *Dope Sheet* or *Graph Editor*, it is a bit tricky with Alembic files. But you can make them visible, too:

When you disable the *Only Show Selected* option (the arrow symbol) in the *Dope Sheet* and *Graph Editor* you can see the keyframes. In the *Timeline* there is no button, but in the *View* menu you can disable *Only Keyframes from Selected Channels*.

The only downside is, if you have many keyframed objects in the scene they will now all show up. To get rid of them, you could disable their visibility in the viewport (maybe with a separate collection).  Not the most elegant solution, but a workaround.

[image: alembic keyframes]

Comment: Thank you. It worked and you're right there's a lot of keyframes that show up but it did allow me to find the keys I was looking for. I wish it was as easier but I won't complain. The solution was solved.